What is the industrial alternative to dialysis?
I want to separate a recombinant protein from imidazole. Both of them are in a solution of pH 8. I was thinking of using ion exchange chromatography with cationite: the imidazole being positively charged will bind to the column. The problem is that my protein's isoelectric point is at pH 9.2 and it is also positive and it will also bind to the column resin. I could work at a different pH, but I'd like to avoid that.
I think that an alternative would be a desalting column, but I don't know if in this way I will get a good yield or if the protein will be diluted. What do you recommend?

Desalting columns dilute by a factor of less than 2. Sometime, dialysis also dilutes (depends on the osmolarity of the inner and outer solution). Sometimes, there is a second purification step that concentrates the sample again, so then it is not so important.

@Karsten Thank you! So, in both cases dillution is not much of an issue because we can concentrate the sample again. What about the yield in the case of desalting columns? Do you think desalting columns would be a good alternative to dialysis?

Which one is better (or something else) depends on the scale and on the frequency of running the process. The yields are comparable. I didn't write an answer because there is not enough information in the question. Also, it might be better to consult with someone on site rather than via the internet.

@Karsten Thank you! I am thinking about this in a theoretical context, not a practical one, so this is why I was wondering if there is a most feasible way to perform this separation in general.
